# DatasetV1Adapter returning unexpected datatype

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to run my own database into code that is based in MNIST

The MNIST value from load is

```
{'test': <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>,
 'train': <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {image: (28, 28, 1), label: ()}, types: {image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}>}
```

What I am getting is:

```
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((None, 224, 224, 3), (None, 10)), types: (tf.float32, tf.bool)>
```

I really don't know how to fix this as it seems to be preventing my model from training, returning the following error:

```
 ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_12 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 150528 but received input with shape [32, 784]
```

Tried loading database using the tensor flow method

Answer (score 0):

Since now your images are coloured(RGB) images so I hope you have changed the input layer accordingly. If so, then problem is in rest of the model layers, they are not receiving the expected input shapes. You have to make changes in their parameter values like strides, kernel size etc.

If you are not sure, then use some model that has been implemented on RGB images.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was looking into the model part of my notebook and it looks like size and channels weren't matching. Training is taking forever as I am training a dense GAN. Will get some results soon